# Enabling network connection on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I was playing around with the network connection last weekend without really knowing what I was doing. Now when I turn on my laptop both wifi/ ethernet connections are disabled by default. After lots of trial and error, I have found that the following command enables my internet connection:
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart && sudo dhclient`.

What do I need to do to not need to enter this every time I restart my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a file `network.sh` with the following commands:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
/usr/sbin/dhclient
```

Add the line to crontab, `sudo crontab -e`:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /home/$USER/network.sh
```

Change `$USER` with your Username.